# Automating wpf application with winObject of 'internet explore server'

Tags: sapui5, hp-uft

How can HP UFT be forced to recognise the objects inside the browser as DOM rather than WPF objects? The application is a SAPUI5 javascript web page displayed inside of a WPF application (SAP Agentry). Object spy describes the nativeclass as: Internet Explorer_Server

Active add-ins:
Web (SAPUI5, SAPWebExt)
WPF

HP-UFT recognises the parent window as WPF and only captures objects based on the WPF object model. Web/DOM objects are ignored.

As a workaround im resorting to Click(x,y) / Low-level recording.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HP-UFT will detect browser dom objects, if the application is registered using the ["Register New Browser Control"](https://uft-help.saas.hpe.com/en/14.01/UFT_Help/Content/Addins_Guide/register_browser_CONCEPT.htm).

Answer provide by [James Xue](https://community.saas.hpe.com/t5/user/viewprofilepage/user-id/165706) in post in the HPE\MicroFocus community forums: [Browser Controls inside of Applications](https://community.saas.hpe.com/t5/Unified-Functional-Testing/Automating-wpf-application-with-winObject-of-internet-explore/m-p/1615587/highlight/true#M23048)

Comment: You should copy the answer (or at least the gist of it) here so that if the link dies the answer will remain available to the community.